# Count Query with joins needed

Tags: sql

i have table as

`Dept`

```
DEPTNO  DNAME   LOC
10  ACCOUNTING  NEW YORK
20  RESEARCH    DALLAS
30  SALES   CHICAGO
40  OPERATIONS  BOSTON
```

and another table as

`Emp`

```
EMPNO   ENAME   JOB          MGR    HIREDATE    SAL     COMM    DEPTNO
7369    SMITH   CLERK       7902    12/17/1980  800     NULL     20
7499    ALLEN   SALESMAN    7698    2/20/1981   1600    300      30
7521    WARD    SALESMAN    7698    2/22/1981   1250    500      30
7566    JONES   MANAGER     7839    4/2/1981    2975    NULL     20
7654    MARTIN  SALESMAN    7698    9/28/1981   1250    1400     30
7698    BLAKE   MANAGER     7839    5/1/1981    2850    NULL     30
7782    CLARK   MANAGER     7839    6/9/1981    2450    NULL     10
7788    SCOTT   ANALYST     7566    12/9/1982   3000    NULL     20
7839    KING    PRESIDENT   NULL    11/17/1981  5000    NULL     10
7844    TURNER  SALESMAN    7698    9/8/1981    1500    0        30
7876    ADAMS   CLERK       7788    1/12/1983   1100    NULL     20
7900    JAMES   CLERK       7698    12/3/1981   950     NULL     30
7902    FORD    ANALYST     7566    12/3/1981   3000    NULL     20
7934    MILLER  CLERK       7782    1/23/1982   1300    NULL     10
```

My question : List ALL the department names and their employee count. Count should include only those employees whose hire date is greater than 1981

Result: should be like this

```
DNAME       EMPCOUNT
ACCOUNTING    1
OPERATIONS    0
RESEARCH      2
SALES         0
```

Comment: please try to make that more readable by better formatting your tables

Comment: Hope this is the format needed..excuse for the confusion

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you post the queries you've tried?

Comment: i tried with the below query..but i didnt get the required output

Comment: SELECT DNAME,
       count(emp.deptno) AS EMPCOUNT
FROM DEPT
LEFT JOIN emp ON DEPT.DEPTNO = emp.DEPTNO
WHERE YEAR(hiredate)>1981
GROUP BY emp.deptno

Comment: I mean: have you tried anything *yourself*? (please read [this article](http://whathaveyoutried.com))

Comment: i didnt tried your query..the query which i tried is shown above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT    dname,
          SUM(CASE WHEN emp.hierdate > '1981/01/01' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM      dept 
LEFT JOIN emp ON dept.deptno = emp.empno
GROUP BY  dname
```

Comment: This will exclude departments with no employees. LEFT JOIN should handle it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
SELECT Dept.DNAME, COUNT(Emp.EMPNO) 
FROM Dept LEFT JOIN Emp ON Dept.DEPTNO = Emp.DEPTNO
WHERE Emp.HIREDATE > '1981/01/01'
GROUP BY Dept.DNAME
```

Comment: This will exclude departments with no employees hired after 1981

Answer (score 1):

It involves a bit of trickery in order to get the departments with 0 matching employees

```
   SELECT Dept.DNAME, COALESCE(t.cnt, 0) AS count
     FROM Dept 
LEFT JOIN (  SELECT deptno, count(*)
               FROM Emp
              WHERE HIREDATA > '1981/01/01'
           GROUP BY deptno) as t
       ON t.deptno = Dept.deptno
```

Comment: too cumbersome, don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

First, understand how to join (read about `inner join`, `left join` and `right join`).

Once you've got that, you should be able to write a query like this:

```
-- First example
select dept.dname, count(emp.empId)
from dept left join emp on dept.deptNo = emp.deptNo
group by dept.dname;
```

or this:

```
-- Second example
select dept.dname, sum(case when emp.empId is not null then 1 else 0 end)
from dept left join emp on dept.deptNo = emp.deptNo
group by dept.dname;
```

Check [SQL fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7f48d0/7)

Comment: This will not show you the departments with 0 matching employees.

Comment: i asked your help..not suggestions and neways will check your query and let you know if it should be up vote or accepted. :)