# Count on multiple tables with missing zero counts

Tags: mysql, database

I am running this query to return data with count < 0. It works fine until count is > 0 and < 50. But when count becomes 0, it doesnot return the data. Count is defined by `` coupons`.`status ``. On count zero, there will be no data in `coupons` table with `status` as 1. This is creating the issue, as it omits the whole row.

```
SELECT count(*) AS count, clients.title, plans.name 
FROM `coupons`
    INNER JOIN `clients` ON `coupons`.`client_id` = `clients`.`id`  
    INNER JOIN `plans` ON `coupons`.`plan_id` = `plans`.`id`
WHERE `coupons`.`status` = 1
GROUP BY `coupons`.`client_id`, `coupons`.`plan_id` 
HAVING count < 50
```

Please help how to fix it.

Table definitions.

```
coupons (id, client_id, plan_id, customer_id, status, code)
plans (id, name)
clients (id, name...)
client_plans (id, client_id, plan_id)
```

Basically, a client can have multiple plans and a plan can belong to multiple clients.

Coupons table stores predefined coupons which can be allocated to customers. Non allocated coupons have status as `0`, while as allocated coupons get status as `1`

Here I am trying to fetch non allocated client wise, plan wise coupon count where either the count is less than 50 or count has reached 0

For example,

If coupons table as 10 rows of client_id = 1 & plan_id = 1 with status as 1, it should return count as 10, but when the table has 0 rows with client_id = 1 and plan_id = 1 with status as 1, it does not return anything in the above query.

Comment: I dont know what exactly your goal is but i guess you could use a LEFT Join. You could start with the clients table, left join on coupons (now you get a result row for your count zero but with NULL Values)

Comment: It should right per your where condition.

Comment: Describe what you're after in plain English, don't reference specific columns and provide sample data with expected results. For example Do you want a count of all coupons used by each clients and the related plan?

Comment: I want to get all coupons with count less than 50 including 0. This way I am able to get all coupons with count less than 50, but not 0 count coupons.

Comment: LEFT JOIN clients and left join plans  though coupons.status=1 may still eliminate some of the coupons.

Comment: Actually coupons table can have status as 0 or 1. I am trying to count all coupons with count 1 and count less than 50. But the issue is, when count will be 0, there will be no rows with status as 1. So it is where I get stuck. At that time, it should return the row with count 0

Comment: Please look at the answers posted to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24917403/count-query-with-joins-needed/24917595

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your inputs, this worked.

```
select 
    sum(CASE WHEN `coupons`.`status` = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as count,     
    clients.title, 
    plans.name 
from 
    `clients` 
left join 
    `coupons` 
on 
    `coupons`.`client_id` = `clients`.`id` 
left join 
    `plans` 
on 
    `coupons`.`plan_id` = `plans`.`id` 
group by 
    `coupons`.`client_id`, 
    `coupons`.`plan_id` 
having 
    count < 50
```

Answer (score 0):

With the inner joins, the query is not going to return any "zero" counts.

If you want to return "zero" counts, you are going to need an outer join somewhere.

But it's not clear what you are actually trying to count.

Assuming that what you are trying to get is a count of rows from **`coupons`**, for every possible combination of rows from **`plans`** and **`clients`**, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(`coupons`.`client_id`) AS `count`
     , clients.title
     , plans.name
  FROM `plans`
 CROSS 
  JOIN `clients`
  LEFT
  JOIN `coupons`
    ON `coupons`.`client_id` = `clients`.`id`
   AND `coupons`.`plan_id`   = `plans`.`id`  
   AND `coupons`.`status`    = 1
 GROUP
    BY `clients`.`id`
     , `plans`.`id`
HAVING `count` < 50
```

---

This is just a guess at result set you are expecting to return. Absent table definitions, example data, and the expected result, we're just guessing.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

Based on your comment, it sounds like you want conditional aggregation.

To "count" only the rows in `coupons` that have `status=1`, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT SUM( `coupons`.`status` = 1 ) AS `count`
     , clients.title
     , plans.name
  FROM `coupons`

  JOIN `plans`
    ON `plans`.`id` = `coupons`.`plan_id`

  JOIN `clients`
    ON `clients`.`id` = `coupons`.`client_id`

 GROUP
    BY `clients`.`id`
     , `plans`.`id`

HAVING `count` < 50
```

There are other expressions you can use to get the conditional "count". For example

```
SELECT COUNT( IF(`coupons`.`status`=1, 1, NULL) ) AS `count`
```

or

```
SELECT SUM( IF(`coupons`.`status`=1, 1, 0) ) AS `count`
```

or, for a more ANSI standards compatible approach

```
SELECT SUM( CASE WHEN `coupons`.`status` = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS `count`
```

Comment: Updated question. Your answer return 0 count records as well, except it gets all clients / all plans. I want the combination to restrict based on coupons table, as the table contains, client_id, plan_id combination.